# Laravel Eloquent - Unable to Retrieve Relationship Data

Tags: php, laravel

I want to retrieve a join table from database using `Laravel Eloquent`. I am able to get the relationship but how do I want to get the detail that belongs to the join table? For example, I have an `applicants` and `applicant_children` tables. The `applicant_children` table is the join table for both parents and children on the `applicants` table. The details that I get is just the parent details.

**Applicant.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\ApplicantChildren;

class Applicant extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function childrens(){
        return $this->hasMany(ApplicantChildren::class, 'ic_staf', 'ic');
    }

}
```

**ApplicantChildren.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Applicant;

class ApplicantChildren extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function children(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Applicant::class, 'ic_anak', 'ic');
    }

    public function parent(){
        return $this->hasOne(Applicant::class, 'ic', 'ic_staf');
    }
}
```

**RegistrationController.php**

```
public function show($id) {    
    $applicantDetails = Applicant::
    with('childrens')
    ->find($id);

    dd($applicantDetails);
}
```

Example of output:

[image: Result]

How do I want to get the details of the children just like the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get details like this

```
foreach ($applicantDetails->childrens as $child) {
    var_dump($child->children);
    var_dump($child->parent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have the children data in your sample output. Only you have to do is iterate through that object

Comment: foreach ($applicantDetails->childrens as $child) {
   dd($child);
}

Answer (score 0):

just use the relationship name as follows :

print_r($applicantDetails->childrens);

The above will print the childrens data.